# SMBus ARP working example

Tags: arduino, i2c, smbus, arp

I've been playing around with an arduino and a few sensors when I came across this amazing communication protocol **I2C** with which a master can communicate with all of the sensors (or slaves in a more general term) on the bus. So far so good. I was wondering is it safe and convenient enough to build the whole hardware around I2C given that all the devices on the I2C bus need to have a **unique** address?

Let's say there's a product line where multiple slaves can connect to the bus (emphasis on CAN and not MUST). How shall I/we solve the problem of assigning a unique address to each slave individually?

I found out [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/85646/i2c-automatic-address-assignment) thread where the same problem is addressed but it lacks any working examples. More precisely, can someone add a working example where a setup involving arduino(s) is using SMBus ARP protocol to assign address to all the slaves.

**EDIT:** I found [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/327482/multiple-i2c-devices-with-the-same-address) thread as well but not just it **lacks any working example** but requires a lot deeper understanding of the circuit which did not make sense given my use case is not to get into the design of the circuit at this micro-level.

Comment: How about? http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=10896#i2csummary

Comment: Are you specifically referring to I2C or SMBUS? SMBUS is an extension to I2C. I2C does not have ARP.

Comment: What you will find amazing about I2C is that lockup is a valid state. You’ll need timeouts and retries.

Comment: @Tony the link you've shared is on I2C, where the slaves have an address. Tony Justme what I am looking for is a way to dynamically assign addresses to the slaves. While SMBus is an extension of I2C, I couldn't find a working example of it used in a situation where address assignment to slave is dynamic and not preloaded.

Comment: How will a protocol uniquely address a target without isolating it or a predetermined address?  CDMA/RB?

Comment: @Tony check this out https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/85646/i2c-automatic-address-assignment

Comment: Contention detection/multiple access with a Random Back off algorithm and host reversal . Nice